# linux based router iptable rule direct all traffic for a specific MAC

Tags: linux, iptables

I have a linux based router.  I'm trying to create an iptable rule to redirect traffic for a specific client using its mac address. Here is the rule I have now (which isn't working):

```
 iptables -t nat -A prerouting_lan -m mac --mac-source $mac -i br-lan -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to $ipaddr
```

What am I doing wrong?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EV

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the "--to" in the DNAT field to "--to-destination". From "man iptables":

```
   DNAT
   This  target  is  only  valid in the nat table, in the PREROUTING and OUTPUT chains, and user-defined chains which are only called
   from those chains.  It specifies that the destination address of the packet should be modified (and all  future  packets  in  this
   connection will also be mangled), and rules should cease being examined.  It takes one type of option:

   --to-destination [ipaddr][-ipaddr][:port[-port]]
```

Comment: Hmmm...Unfortunately, that doesn't work.  I'm still working on it.  Any other ideas?